# Fixing MUI TextField input text area

Tags: css, material-ui, grid, textfield

Currently a beginner student to grid and mui, but I am trying to create a text area that can hold many values. I have a character string of 2689 and I populate it in MUI TextField but it's giving me some weird visual bugs.

[image]

[image]

I have like 3 rows at the top hidden but can't see them because my vertical scroll bar is at the top. And if I were to scroll down you can see a border going across the text area. I believe this might be from the InputLabelProps.

Here's my code my component portion of the code

```
 <Box hidden={tabValue !== 1}>
                <Grid container spacing={2}>
                    <Grid item xs={12} md={10}>
                        <TextField
                            id="runIds"
                            label="Enter Run IDs"
                            multiline
                            variant="outlined"
                            fullWidth
                            value={runIds}
                            onChange={(e) => setRunIds(e.target.value)}
                            InputProps={{
                            style: {
                                marginTop: '10px',
                                height: 'auto',
                                maxHeight: '150px',
                                overflowY: 'auto',
                                border: '1px solid #bdbdbd',
                            },
                            }}
                            InputLabelProps={{
                                style: {
                                    top: '-5px',
                                },
                            }}
                        />
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid container spacing={2}>
                            <Grid item xs={12} sm={6} md={4}>
                                <FormControl fullWidth variant="outlined">
                                    <Row style={{ justifyContent: 'center', display: 'flex', margin: '10px'}}>
                                    <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs}>
                                        <Col lg={6} style={{ marginBottom: '20px' }}>
                                            <DesktopDatePicker
                                                className={classes.desktopColumn}
                                                label="Date From:"
                                                inputFormat="MM/DD/YYYY"
                                                value={dateFrom}
                                                name="from"
                                                onChange={handleDateFromChange}
                                                renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} InputProps={{ style: { fontSize: '1.1rem' } }} />}
                                            />
                                        </Col>
                                        <Col lg={6} style={{ marginBottom: '20px' }}>
                                            <DesktopDatePicker
                                                className={classes.desktopColumn}
                                                label="Date To:"
                                                inputFormat="MM/DD/YYYY"
                                                value={dateTo}
                                                name="to"
                                                onChange={handleDateToChange}
                                                renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} InputProps={{ style: { fontSize: '1.1rem' } }} />}
                                            />
                                        </Col>
                                    </LocalizationProvider>
                                    </Row>
                                </FormControl>
                            </Grid>
                            <Grid item xs={12} sm={6} md={4}>
                                <Button
                                    variant="contained"
                                    color="primary"
                                    onClick={handleImportRunIdsClick}
                                    style={{ marginTop: '20px' }}
                                >
                                    Import Run IDs
                                </Button>
                            </Grid>
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                </Box>
```

This is for what you see under the highlighted 'Runs' tab. I am using makeStyles for some Dialog styling. Just in case (if needed) here's the whole component and it's class styling.

```
 const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
        dialogWrapper: {
            padding: theme.spacing(2),
            position: 'absolute',
            top: theme.spacing(2)
        },
        dialogTitle: {
            display: 'flex',
            justifyContent: 'space-between',
            alignItems: 'center',
        },
        closeIcon: {
            marginLeft: 'auto',
        },
        storagesContainer: {
            display: 'flex',
            justifyContent: 'space-evenly', 
            gap: 5, 
            margin: '20px 0px'
        },
        alertContainer: {
            display: 'flex',
            alignItems: 'center',
            marginLeft: '20px 0px',
            overflow: 'hidden',
          },
        inputContainer: {
            display: 'flex',
            alignItems: 'center',
            margin: '15px 0px',
            marginLeft: 8
            //overflow: 'hidden',
        },
        outlineInput: {
            height: 20,
            width: 50,
            marginLeft: 10,
            marginRight: 10,
        },
        buttonContainer: {
            display: 'flex',
            justifyContent: 'space-evenly',
            overflow: 'hidden',
        },
        defaultButton: {
            margin: theme.spacing(1),
            background: 'linear-gradient(113.96deg, #E9F5F5 100%, #D9E7F4 100%)',
            border: '0.5px solid #CCCCCC',
            boxSizing: 'border-box',
            borderRadius: '4px',
            color: '#189AB4',
            width: 150,
            '&:disabled': {
                background: '#f0f0f0', // Change this to the desired disabled background color
                color: '#666666', // Change this to the desired disabled text color
            },
        },
        button: {
            margin: theme.spacing(1),
            background: '-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right bottom, from(#0075a9), to(#003049))',
            border: '0.5px solid #CCCCCC',
            boxSizing: 'border-box',
            borderRadius: '4px',
            color: 'white',
            width: 150,
            '&:disabled': {
                background: '#f0f0f0', // Change this to the desired disabled background color
                color: '#666666', // Change this to the desired disabled text color
            },
        },
        deleteButton: {
            margin: theme.spacing(1),
            background: 'linear-gradient(98.3deg, rgb(128, 0, 0) 10.6%, rgb(255, 0, 0) 97.7%)',
            border: '0.5px solid #CCCCCC',
            boxSizing: 'border-box',
            borderRadius: '4px',
            color: 'white',
            width: 150,
            '&:disabled': {
                background: '#f0f0f0', // Change this to the desired disabled background color
                color: '#666666', // Change this to the desired disabled text color
            },
        },
        allButtonsContainer: {
            display: 'flex',
            justifyContent: 'space-between',
            margin: '15px 0px',
        },
        desktopColumn: {
            fontSize: 10
        },
    }));

const classes = useStyles();

    return (
        <>
        <Dialog disableEnforceFocus onClose={handleClose} aria-labelledby="customized-dialog-title" open={isOpen} fullWidth maxWidth={'md'} classes={{paper: classes.dialogWrapper}} BackdropProps={Boolean(deleteStatus) ? { onClick: () => {} } : {}}>
        <DialogTitle>
            <div style={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'space-between', alignItems: 'center' }}>
                <Typography variant="h6">Storage Management</Typography>
                <IconButton onClick={handleClose}>
                    <CloseIcon />
                </IconButton>
            </div>
        </DialogTitle>
        <div style={{ display: 'grid', gridTemplateRows: 'repeat(2, 1fr)', gridTemplateColumns: 'repeat(2, 1fr)', gap: '10px', marginBottom: 30, marginLeft: 30 }}>
            <div style={{ display: 'flex', alignItems: 'center' }}>
                <Typography>Stored Runs: {runInfoCount}</Typography>
            </div>
            <div style={{ display: 'flex', alignItems: 'center' }}>
                <Typography>Available Storage (runs): {diskSpace}</Typography>
            </div>
            <div style={{ display: 'flex', alignItems: 'center' }}>
                <Typography>Storage to be freed with current rules (runs): {calcFreeSpace}</Typography>
            </div>
            <div style={{ display: 'flex', alignItems: 'center' }}>
                <Typography>Last clean-up completed at: {lastCleanupDate}</Typography>
            </div>
        </div>
        <Tabs value={tabValue} onChange={handleTabChange} indicatorColor='primary'>
                <Tab label="Rules" />
                <Tab label="Runs" />
        </Tabs>
            <DialogContent dividers style={{ overflow: 'hidden', margin: 0 }}>
                <Box hidden={tabValue !== 0}>
                    <div className={classes.inputContainer}>
                        <Typography>Alert when available storage is below:</Typography>
                        <OutlinedInput
                            id="alertRun"
                            name='alertRun'
                            type="number"
                            value={values.alertRun}
                            onChange={handleInputChange}
                            className={classes.outlineInput}
                            disabled={Boolean(delete_run_request_status)}
                        />
                        <Typography>runs</Typography>
                    </div>
                    <Stack spacing={1} margin={1}>
                        <div className={classes.inputContainer}>
                            <Typography>Remove all data for runs older than:</Typography>
                            <OutlinedInput
                                id="allRuns"
                                name='allRuns'
                                type="number"
                                value={values.allRuns}
                                onChange={handleInputChange}
                                className={classes.outlineInput}
                                disabled={Boolean(delete_run_request_status)}
                            />
                            <Typography>months</Typography>
                        </div>
                        <div className={classes.inputContainer}>
                            <Typography>Remove base-calling quality data for runs older than:</Typography>
                            <OutlinedInput
                                id="baseCallingQuality"
                                name='baseCallingQuality'
                                type="number"
                                value={values.baseCallingQuality}
                                onChange={handleInputChange}
                                className={classes.outlineInput}
                                disabled={Boolean(delete_run_request_status)}
                            />
                            <Typography>months</Typography>
                        </div>
                        <div className={classes.inputContainer}>
                            <Typography>Remove signal quality and wafer maps data for runs older than:</Typography>
                            <OutlinedInput
                                id="signalQualityWafer"
                                name='signalQualityWafer'
                                type="number"
                                value={values.signalQualityWafer}
                                onChange={handleInputChange}
                                className={classes.outlineInput}
                                disabled={Boolean(delete_run_request_status)}
                            />
                            <Typography>months</Typography>
                        </div>
                        <div className={classes.inputContainer}>
                            <Typography>Remove system debug data for runs older than:</Typography>
                            <OutlinedInput
                                id="systemDebug"
                                name='systemDebug'
                                type="number"
                                value={values.systemDebug}
                                onChange={handleInputChange}
                                className={classes.outlineInput}
                                disabled={Boolean(delete_run_request_status)}
                            />
                            <Typography>months</Typography>
                        </div>
                        <div className={classes.inputContainer}>
                            <Typography>Remove amp runs older than:</Typography>
                            <OutlinedInput
                                id="ampRuns"
                                name='ampRuns'
                                type="number"
                                value={values.ampRuns}
                                onChange={handleInputChange}
                                className={classes.outlineInput}
                                disabled={Boolean(delete_run_request_status)}
                            />
                            <Typography>months</Typography>
                        </div>
                    </Stack> 
                    <div className={classes.buttonContainer}>
                        <DialogActions>
                            <Button autoFocus onClick={handleDefaultClick} color="primary" className={classes.defaultButton} disabled={Boolean(delete_run_request_status)}>
                            Default
                            </Button>
                            <Button autoFocus onClick={handleApplyClick} color="primary" className={classes.button} disabled={Boolean(delete_run_request_status)}>
                            Apply
                            </Button>
                        </DialogActions>
                    </div>
                </Box>
                <Box hidden={tabValue !== 1}>
                <Grid container spacing={2}>
                    <Grid item xs={12} md={10}>
                        <TextField
                            id="runIds"
                            label="Enter Run IDs"
                            multiline
                            variant="outlined"
                            fullWidth
                            value={runIds}
                            onChange={(e) => setRunIds(e.target.value)}
                            InputProps={{
                            style: {
                                marginTop: '10px',
                                height: 'auto',
                                maxHeight: '150px',
                                overflowY: 'auto',
                                border: '1px solid #bdbdbd',
                            },
                            }}
                            InputLabelProps={{
                                style: {
                                    top: '-5px',
                                },
                            }}
                        />
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid container spacing={2}>
                            <Grid item xs={12} sm={6} md={4}>
                                <FormControl fullWidth variant="outlined">
                                    <Row style={{ justifyContent: 'center', display: 'flex', margin: '10px'}}>
                                    <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs}>
                                        <Col lg={6} style={{ marginBottom: '20px' }}>
                                            <DesktopDatePicker
                                                className={classes.desktopColumn}
                                                label="Date From:"
                                                inputFormat="MM/DD/YYYY"
                                                value={dateFrom}
                                                name="from"
                                                onChange={handleDateFromChange}
                                                renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} InputProps={{ style: { fontSize: '1.1rem' } }} />}
                                            />
                                        </Col>
                                        <Col lg={6} style={{ marginBottom: '20px' }}>
                                            <DesktopDatePicker
                                                className={classes.desktopColumn}
                                                label="Date To:"
                                                inputFormat="MM/DD/YYYY"
                                                value={dateTo}
                                                name="to"
                                                onChange={handleDateToChange}
                                                renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} InputProps={{ style: { fontSize: '1.1rem' } }} />}
                                            />
                                        </Col>
                                    </LocalizationProvider>
                                    </Row>
                                </FormControl>
                            </Grid>
                            <Grid item xs={12} sm={6} md={4}>
                                <Button
                                    variant="contained"
                                    color="primary"
                                    onClick={handleImportRunIdsClick}
                                    style={{ marginTop: '20px' }}
                                >
                                    Import Run IDs
                                </Button>
                            </Grid>
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                </Box>
            </DialogContent>
                <div className={classes.buttonContainer}>
                    <DialogActions>
                    <Button className={classes.deleteButton} autoFocus onClick={handleDeleteClick} color="primary" disabled={Boolean(delete_run_request_status)}>
                        Delete
                    </Button>
                    </DialogActions>
                </div>
        </Dialog>
        {message ? (
            <PopupMessage
                isOpen={PopUpOpen}
                message={message}
                confirmationMessage={confirmationMessage}
                onOk={confirmationMessage ? handleConfirmationOk : handleConfirmationCancel}
                onCancel={handleConfirmationCancel}
            />
        ) : null}
        </>
    );
```